# I need help parsing a .csv file based on if a string contains a given substring and saving that string to a new file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, file, parsing, csv, substring

Basically, I am searching through a list of foods.  The fields I am using in the .csv file are: the name of the food, the type of the food represented by a number (type of food would be meat, vegetable, fruit, etc).  I want to go through the .csv file line by line, and if the type of food is say a fruit (represented by the number 1), then I want to save that entire line in a new file.  I want to go through the ENTIRE list of foods and save each to the new file.  How could I go about doing this in objective c?  My idea was to search the string for a substring (in this case, the number 1) and if it contains the substring, then I want to save the entire line in a new file, called fruit.  I understand this in theory, but am having trouble understanding how to parse a .csv file in this way.

Comment: CSVs suck. For anyone to give you reasonably good advice on how to handle this case you should post at least the first few "lines" of your file. Or better yet see if you can get the same information in a JSON instead.

Comment: I don't know quite why he's so down on CSV files, but the code Ash Furrow lists is essentially what you need -- not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

NJones is right - CSV files suck and you don't see them often in Objective-C, so try to avoid them.

However, you can load a CSV file with the following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

If you have the contents of a CSV stored in memory, either from a file on disk or from a web service, you can turn it into an array of line records:

```
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

The first line in a CSV file is typically you're header, but after removing it (or ignoring it), it's simply a matter of enumerating over the remaining lines.

```
for (NSString *record in lines) {
    NSArray *values = [record componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //values is now an array of the contents of the CSV file. Do stuff with it.
}
```

This code assumes a lot about the CSV file structure, such as the fact that there are no commas in your food names, etc. In general, avoid CSV files whenever possible. Take a look into persisting data on disk as JSON or, better yet, as a Core Data store.

Comment: I had to learn by experience how awful CSVs are - this code was copied directly from that project, two years after abandoning it :)

Answer (score 1):

-(BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError

{

```
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:absoluteURL 
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];

NSLog(@"------- file string ----- %@",fileString);
if ( nil == fileString )
    return NO;
 NSArray* allLinedStrings = 
[fileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
 [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];   
 NSLog(@"------- file string ----- %@",allLinedStrings); 

// write your code how you want display
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file is fairly simple with a well defined format, you may have the best luck with your own code based upon the suggestion from @Ash Furrow.

If you are facing a more complicated import, you may find the tutorial and CSV parsing class created by Matt Gallagher to be very helpful.  He did a really nice job creating a nice way to deal with CSV files.  You can check it out here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.htmlhttp://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html